# APPS SCRIPT - Get URL and File Name from array of folders ID

Tags: google-apps-script, google-sheets

I would like to get the files URL and Name from an array of folders ID, which I'm retrieing with a script.

[image]

I would like the result to be placed on the Files tab.

The script I'm using for getting the filesID is the following:

```js
function Folders_URL() {
var ss=SpreadsheetApp.getActive().getSheetByName("Overview");

var fldr=DriveApp.getFolderById("someID");

var files=fldr.getFolders();
var names=[],f,str; while (files.hasNext()) {
f=files.next();
names.push([f.getId(), f.getName()]);
}
ss.getRange(4,2,names.length, 2).setValues(names);
}
```

For getting files Names with the URL, I use this code.
It would be very helpful if someone can join both codes or just getting the URLs and File names from the array of foldersID

```js
function getFileNames() {
  var sheet = SpreadsheetApp.getActive().getSheetByName("someLink");
 
  //Range where the links are set
  var links = sheet.getRange("F3:F").getValues();

  var filenames = []; 
  for (var i = 0; i < links.length; i++) {
    var url = links[i][0];
    if (url != "") {
      var filename = SpreadsheetApp.openByUrl(links[i][0]).getName();
      filenames.push([filename]);
    }
  }

  //Define cell range
  var startRow = 3; // print in row 2 since row 1 is the header row
  var fileNameColumn = 4; // Column B = column 2
  var destinationCell = sheet.getRange(startRow, fileNameColumn, filenames.length, filenames[0].length);
  destinationCell.setValues(filenames);
}
```

Please be aware that I cannot share any sheet since I have sensitive information from my end.
Thanks!

**UPDATED ANSWER**

New error when running the script:
[image]

Answer (score 1):

#### Get Urls

I tested this code on my data and it works fine.  If it's not working on your data then the problem is your data.

```
function getUrls() {
  const ss = SpreadsheetApp.getActive();
  const sh = ss.getSheetByName("Sheet0");
  const osh = ss.getSheetByName("Sheet1");
  const vs = sh.getRange(4, 1, sh.getLastRow() - 3, sh.getLastColumn()).getValues();
  let obj = { pA: [] };
  vs.forEach((r, i) => {
    let fldr = DriveApp.getFolderById(r[1]);
    let files = fldr.getFilesByName(r[2]);
    while (files.hasNext()) {
      let file = files.next();
      let name = file.getName();;
      if (!obj.hasOwnProperty(name)) {
        obj[name] = [file.getUrl()];
        obj.pA.push(name)
      } else {
        obj[name].push(file.getUrl())
      }
    }
  });
  if (obj.pA.length > 0) {
    let o = obj.pA.map(p => [p, obj[p].join('\n')]);
    osh.clearContents();
    if(o.length > 0) {
      osh.getRange(1, 1, o.length, o[0].length).setValues(o);
    }
  }
}
```

Comment: I modified vs = sh.getrange(4,2....) and osh.getrange(2,2....) for my code to work but I'm getting   
Exception: Unexpected error while getting the method or property getFolderById on object DriveApp.

Comment: I had id's and filenames reversed

Comment: Got it, by any chance, did the code got updated?

Comment: I'm still getting the same error

Comment: I couldn't see the column names before in your image so I had the wrong columns

Comment: Ok, no problem. I'll wait for the updated code since the error remains

Comment: Please repeat the error and let me know what line number is generating it

Comment: Answer updated, Cooper

Comment: Ok what sheet and column are your folder id's located

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/248390/discussion-between-mau-and-cooper).

Comment: okay try it again

Comment: I just test this script and it runs on my data.